# ReadLn from file >255 chars in pascal

Tags: string, pascal, freepascal

I am trying to read lines that are longer than 255 chars from a file with pascal line by line. I am not allowed to read it char by char and I am glued to the standard settings of free pascal compiler.
What can I do to achieve that? Is it even possible? I read some hints about using blockread but I wasn't able to find enough information about it to get a clue how it's done.

I am open for any suggestions though as long as they fulfill my restrictions.

Thank you very much in advance
cheers
-gladston3

Comment: If you are not allowed to do something, there is probably something in the description that points to what is the goal of the exercise. blockread is possible, that means reading the file as raw binary data, and interpreting it manually.

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite see the problem. This works (Lazarus/FreePascal on Windows 7):

```
program Project1;

const
  FileName = 'test.txt';

procedure WriteLongLines;
var
  S: string;
  T: Text;
begin
  S := StringOfChar('#', 350);
  Assign(T, FileName);
  Rewrite(T);
  Writeln(T, S);
  Writeln(T, S);
  Writeln(T, S);
  Close(T);
end;

var
  T: Text;
  S: string;

begin
  WriteLongLines;
  Assign(T, FileName);
  Reset(T);
  while not EOF(T) do
  begin
    Readln(T, S);
    Writeln(Length(S), ' ', S);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

The lines are 350 characters in length (i.e. > 255). They can be read without a problem. I did not change any of the standard settings.

Lazarus v1.6 from 2016-02-14, FPC 3.0.0.

Just tried it on OS X. Works fine too.
And it also works fine in Ubuntu 16.04.

Hmmm... Don't tell me you are using short strings (max 255 chars)?